# Are Spring Model objects (and their attributes) tied to their respective controller endpoints / templates?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, dependency-injection, thymeleaf

I'm just starting with spring so please bear with me. I've just solved a bug in my code that was coming from my assumption that once an attribute is added to any Model object, it would also be available to the templating implementation at other endpoints.

```
@GetMapping("/user_page")
    public String getUserPage( Model model ) {
        Page page = new Page();
        model.addAttribute("user_page", page);
        return "user_page";
```

In my Thymeleaf template I was able to use this attribute fine at `user_page.html`. Now at another endpoint and template I was also trying to use this `user_page` attribute. Note that it was throwing some errors:

```
Exception evaluating SpringEL expression:
```

and

```
Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1007E: Property or field 'name' cannot be found on null
```

It looks like Thymeleaf couldn't find the `user_page` attribute.

but I also hadn't added a `Model` parameter to the controller that handled this other endpoint. After adding a `Model` to the method parameters and adding the page again `model.addAttribute("user_page", page);`, this time to the controller handling the different endpoint, the problem went away.

Is Spring autowiring non-singleton `Model` objects to these controllers? Why did I have to add the same page instance to the model twice? So are these Models tied specifically to the template (maybe even endpoint) that their respective controller returns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read [Dispatcher Servlet Processing Sequence](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-servlet-sequence).

> Are Spring Model objects (and their attributes) tied to their respective controller endpoints / templates?

There is no such a thing, as "Model's respective controller"; rather, a fresh instance of the `Model`'s implementation gets instantiated each time, any handler method gets invoked.

When an HTTP request hits dispatcher servlet, and the latter passes the servlet request-response objects into the corresponding handler method, Spring MVC's infrastructure looks up the signature of corresponding handler method and passes a fresh instance of the `Model` (along with many others), if it is expected.

You can also use `modelAttribute` element in your template's form, and this way, you will directly bind the data to the handler method's Model parameter, having the argument being pre-filled with the form data. In this case, you can also enable Bean Validation.

Comment: By handler method are you referring to my ```getUserpage``` or a method that gets called as a result of that? I'm having trouble understanding the scope of each ```Model```. Is it safe to say that a @requestmapping method that takes a model only provides that models attributes to the same methods template?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the semantics of your comment, but *handler method* is a method mapped by `@RequestMapping`, and defined within the class annotated by `@Controller`. So, in your case, yes, it is `getUserPage`. [Handler methods](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.3.14.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-introduction) are ones that actually handle HTTP requests and prepare responses.

Comment: To rephrase, If I add a ```Model``` to a handler method, where can I expect to access those  ```Model``` attributes? Only ever a single template?

Comment: In the view, name of the which you return from your handler method. `Model` is just a container/box, where you put the data, and where you fetch the data from, in your front layer (jsp, or any other template, that supports expression language). So, you put data into model and then fetch that data, with their corresponding attribute names, in the template.